# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been consistently getting the same error message for this line of code and I have tried every single possible method I have found to try and resolve this but nothing has worked at all. the Issue if the if statement `If (!user.getid().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()))` I am stuck and getting so frustrated Again I have tried everything.

```
public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {

    private  RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    private UserAdapter userAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false);


        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        readUsers();

        return view; 
    }

    private void readUsers() {

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ignored : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);


                    assert user != null;
                    assert firebaseUser != null;

                    if (!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    }

                }

                userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, false);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: user.getId() is probably returning null. Paste your actual full exception and double check that the line is indeed `!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())`. Either user is null, or user.getId() is null, or firebaseUser.getUid() is null.

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to answer these questions: 
1) What does the JSON at `/Users` looks like (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) What does your `User` class look like?